# Array is returning an Extra "1" in the end (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My array is returning an extra 1 in the end.
here is the array:

```
$item = array(
       'numberofitems' => $_POST['numberofitems']
     );
```

and here is the result:

```
Array (
 [numberofitems] => 4 ) 1
```

View Code:

> result() as $row): $i++; ?> 
>   customer_name
>   ?> customer_address ?> ">

I have tried all ways to get this "4" but somehow it makes it to "41" by adding that "1" in the end. Please let me know whats i'm doing wrong

Comment: Show us more lines of your code. Something else is adding the `1`

Comment: SHow us how you output that array result

Comment: Are you using something like `echo print_r($item);`?

Comment: I think that "1" is array's length :) 

How do you print them?

Comment: try `print_r($item);` .... and not `echo print_r($item);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using echo '<pre>',print_r($item),'</pre>';

Comment: I also tried getting this in another variable that makes it "41"

Answer (score 2):

If you use `print_r()` and do something like :

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($data), '</pre>';
```

You will display `print_r()` `$data` and what `print_r()` returns too (eg. `1`).

Like anyone, you just want display `print_r()` argument, so you must do :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or :

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($data, TRUE), '</pre>';
```